# How do I stagger divs like Google Plus?

Tags: jquery, html, css

As you see, in Google+, each posts are staggered(?) like this image

[image: Google+]

And to implement view like this, I used StaggeredGridView in Android, but I can't make sense which library or CSS tricks is needed to implement this in the web.

Height of each divs are different, and `float:left` didn't worked as I thought. They made a large space in each divs like this:

[image: Didn't worked with float:left]

So how do I make the divs like Google Plus? And are there any key words to find this layout?

Comment: There are libraries for that, such as http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Google 'masonry layout'.

Comment: http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: Oh, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Flexbox.

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox-container > div.column {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="column">
    <div>
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
      <p>Ille vivere. Ut ad te quaerebam ... purgare caeli. Sunt uh ... nonnullus propter errorem qui de rebus inter nos et iacere puto suus in causa, id est in mensa. Levir meus, priusquam oppugnarent tempus quis, admonere dicitur. Credo quod idem mihi
        praesidium.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be a great way to implement this, but flexbox is too early technology yet..

Comment: Oh yeah, that was true.. Well.. all of the major smartphones will support flexbox, aren't they?